# How to set nginx reverse proxy to an SSL site without certificate?

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy

There is a function using TCP pass through like this:

```
stream {
    upstream web_server {
        # the site to be visited is https://whatismyip.com, below is its real address
        server 104.27.194.88:443;
    }

    server {
        listen 443;
        ssl_preread on;
        proxy_pass web_server;
    }
}
```

[reference](https://serversforhackers.com/c/tcp-load-balancing-with-nginx-ssl-pass-thru)

Therefore, if I type the public IP address of that nginx server after "https://" on my browser, given all the firewalls allowed, can I in fact reach the target site?

Actually what I got is whether to allow the ssl certificate from nginx server, then allowed, but got 403 forbidden by cloudflare.

If something went wrong, how to improve? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

First you need to change in your `hosts` file (or your DNS if you have access to your DNS server configuration) and add an entry similar with:

```
192.168.1.10 whatismyip.com
```

Or for DNS:

```
whatismyip.com IN A 192.168.1.10
```

Where `192.168.1.10` is the IP where Nginx is listening. In the browser use https://whatismyip.com and don't connect with the IP.

The config should use a hostname, because the whatismyip.com's IP address might change:

```
stream {
    upstream web_server {
        server whatismyip.com:443;
    }

    server {
        listen 443;
        ssl_preread on;
        proxy_pass web_server;
    }
}
```

Comment: I know you are trying to cheat the machine with internet browser to think whatismyip.com as 192.168.1.10 (as my nginx server ip). But the problem is that in no way I can even `telnet 192.168.1.10 443` at first while `telnet 104.27.194.88 443` is affirmative.

Comment: It's not cheating. It is how host name resolution works. You need to make sure you have something listening on `192.168.1.10:443` You can check this on a Linux machine with: `sudo ss -tlnp | grep :443`

Comment: Yes, thanks. What is interesting is that I was able to telnet the 443 port (in fact 445) on that nginx server. But as I try to open the page by a Linux internet browser via `links https://127.0.0.1:445` it negotiates the ssl protocol and then failed with 403 forbidden.

Comment: You need to use the proper hostname, not the IP, that is why you need to change `hosts` file. See Name Based Virtual Hosting: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_hosting#Name-based

Comment: The hostname is used both for SSL certificate validation and for HTTP name based virtual hosting.

Comment: You have `hosts` file format reversed, it should be `<ipaddr> <name> [<alias> ...]`

Comment: Yes it is. I will fix it. Thank you.